# Using the Set() method of an image.Image or *image.RGBA

Tags: image, go, set, undefined

I am doing some practice with the Go image package with my free time this summer.

```
package main

import (

    "os"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "image/color"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"

)

func main(){

    file , err := os.OpenFile("C:/Sources/go3x3.png", os.O_RDWR, os.FileMode(0777))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    img , err := png.Decode(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    img.At(0,0).RGBA()
    fmt.Println("type:", reflect.TypeOf(img))

    m := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 640, 480))
    fmt.Println("type:", reflect.TypeOf(m))
    m.Set(5, 5, color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255})
    img.Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{136, 0, 21, 255})
}
```

The problem here is when I run it with the `img.Set` commented out I get this result

```
type: *image.RGBA
type: *image.RGBA
```

but when it's uncommented I get an error saying

```
img.Set undefined (type image.Image has no field or method Set)
```

I'm assuming I'm using reflect wrong, I'm still fully grasping the whole interface and type definitions in Go.

Answer (score 10):

To expand on
[a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/anonymous)
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30228156/55504):

[`png.Decode`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#Decode) may create one of several different underlying image types (`*image.Gray`, `*image.RGBA`, `*image.Paletted`, `*image.NRGBA`, etc).
It returns whatever image it created as an `image.Image` interface which **provides read only access** to the data.

However, all (most?) of the actual image types it returns do implement the `Set` method for simple write access.
The way you can safely test for and use this method is via the existing [`draw.Image`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Image) interface from the `image/draw` package. It's just this:

```
// From image/draw:
// Image is an image.Image with a Set method to change a single pixel.
type Image interface {
        image.Image
        Set(x, y int, c color.Color)
}
```

So you could do something like:

```
func drawablePNGImage(r io.Reader) (draw.Image, error) {
    img, err := png.Decode(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    dimg, ok := img.(draw.Image)
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%T is not a drawable image type", img)
    }
    return dimg, nil
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/iikV4i0FdI) (shows an example calling all the `image.Image` methods as well as `Set`).

Edit for Go1.17+:

Note that Go1.17 added [`draw.RGBA64Image`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#RGBA64Image) with a `SetRGBA64` method. As with `draw.Image`, all of the standard image types implement this. The advantage of this method is that the color values are not boxed in the `color.Color` interface type so doing many pixel operations can be faster.
Also note that [Go1.18 added optimisations](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#image/draw) to the [`draw.Draw` and `draw.DrawMask`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/draw#Draw) fallback implementations for images that implement the optional `draw.RGBA64Image` and [`image.RGBA64Image`](https://pkg.go.dev/image#RGBA64Image) interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

`reflect.TypeOf(img)` gives you the reflection type of the value in the interface `img`, if its an interface. In this case, `img` *is* an interface, an `image.Image` which contains an `*image.RGBA`.

You can fix your code by converting `img` to an `*image.RGBA`, or more robustly, define an interface type with the right `Set` method, and convert `img` to that (the `draw.Image` interface in `"image/draw"` works perfectly for this, as noted by @DaveC). The interface type is preferable if you aren't sure that `png.Decode` will always give you an `*image.RGBA` for the .png files you have.

```
img.(*image.RGBA).Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{136, 0, 21, 255})
```

or

```
type Setter interface {
    Set(x, y int, c color.Color)
}

img.(Setter).Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{136, 0, 21, 255})
```

or (probably best):

```
import "image/draw"

...

img.(draw.Image).Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{136, 0, 21, 255})
```

Comment: A slightly better version of that interface already exists as `draw.Image`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30243259/55504) for one way to use it.

Answer (score -1):

The **compiler is correct**, the [image.Image](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Image) type is an interface that does not include the Set() function.

I am not an expert at the image library but my cursory look at the types seems to suggest you can take an Image type and use the `Bounds()` method to get a [image.Rectangle](http://golang.org/pkg/image/#Rectangle) to create a new RGBA type as done previously in your example code.

```
// Your current image manipulation
m := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 640, 480))
fmt.Println("type:", reflect.TypeOf(m))
m.Set(5, 5, color.RGBA{255, 0, 0, 255})

// You can create a image.RGBA type by passing the image.Rectangle
// returned from image.Image.Bounds()
m = image.NewRGBA(img.Bounds())
m.Set(0, 0, color.RGBA{136, 0, 21, 255})
```

This is a strict answer to your type issue but I don't have any gurantee it accomplishes your end goals.